# Why does assign (lambda) sometimes reads the entire column rather each individual row when assigning values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a DataFrame with a code in a column. I want to extract the first digit from said code and add to a different column so I can use it to merge it with a different DF.

My code is:

```py
df_a = df_a.assign(index_a = lambda x: int(str(x.code)[0]))
```

When I use:

```py
df_a = df_a.assign(index_a = lambda x: x.code)
```

This works and I get a new DF with the extra "Code" column and the entire code. If do any operations here like x.code + 1 or x.code * 5 it works.

Then, when I try to convert each code to a string by doing:

```py
df_a = df_a.assign(index_a = lambda x: str(x.code))
```

Instead of getting each row with a string code, all rows receive the value of the entire column converted into a massive string.

I had a similar problem in the past trying to navigate lambda functions and learned that as long as I did x + 0 before converting, everything worked okay, but this time it's not working.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's so because str(x.code)  convert the whole column each time, try this instead

```
df_a['code'] = df_a['code'].apply(str)
```

Comment: Thanks! Using this method, I was able to do:

df_a['index_a'] = df_a['code'].apply(str)
df_a['index_a'] = df_a['index_a'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

and get my final result. Added a step in the dataframe generation to create the index_a column before this operation and works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

`str(x.code)` will convert the whole series to string, so that's not probably you want.

Consider following dataframe:

```
  col1
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
```

Then you can do:

```py
df["col1"] = pd.Categorical(df["col1"])

df = df.assign(index_a=lambda x: x["col1"].cat.codes.astype(str))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 index_a
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    C       2
3    A       0
```

`index_a` column now contains numbers as strings.